# Random Forest optimization with tuning and cross-validation

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest

I'm working with a large data set, so hope to remove extraneous variables and tune for an optimal m variables per branch.  In R, there are two methods, rfcv and tuneRF, that help with these two tasks.  I'm attempting to combine them to optimize parameters.

rfcv works roughly as follows:

```
create random forest and extract each variable's importance;
while (nvar > 1) {
    remove the k (or k%) least important variables;
    run random forest with remaining variables, reporting cverror and predictions
}
```

Presently, I've recoded rfcv to work as follows:

```
create random forest and extract each variable's importance;
while (nvar > 1) {
    remove the k (or k%) least important variables;
    tune for the best m for reduced variable set;
    run random forest with remaining variables, reporting cverror and predictions;
}
```

This, of course, increases the run time by an order of magnitude.  My question is how necessary this is (it's been hard to get an idea using toy datasets), and whether any other way could be expected to work roughly as well in far less time.

Answer (score 11):

As always, the answer is it depends on the data.  On one hand, if there aren't any irrelevant features, then you can just totally skip feature elimination.  The tree building process in the random forest implementation already tries to select predictive features, which gives you some protection against irrelevant ones.

Leo Breiman gave a talk where he introduced 1000 irrelevant features into some medical prediction task that had only a handful of real features from the input domain.  When he eliminated 90% of the features using a single filter on variable importance, the next iteration of random forest didn't pick any irrelevant features as predictors in its trees.